# How to check if all attributes is null or empty string with lodash?

Tags: javascript, lodash

I have an object:

```
const obj = {
    name: "",
    age: null
}
```

How can I check if all attributes is null or "" with lodash ? Is so, return true, if some attributes is not null or "" then false.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

With lodash you can use `_.every()` to check if all properties are empty:

```js
const obj = {
  name: '',
  age: null
}

const result = _.every(obj, v => v === '' || _.isNull(v))

console.log(result)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.15/lodash.js"></script>
```

Comment: @OriDrori I guess `_.isNil` is a better choice here, that will check for *undefined* as well

Comment: According to the description it's empty string or `null`, but that's a good options as well.

Answer (score 1):

You could use [`Object.values`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_objects/Object/values), [`Array.every`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/every) and [`Array.includes`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/includes):

```js
const obj1 = { name: "", age: null }
const obj2 = { name: "", age: null, b: 0 }
const obj3 = { name: "", age: null, b: NaN }
const obj4 = { name: "", age: null, b: false }
const obj5 = { name: "", age: null, b: undefined }

function checkEmptyOrNull(obj) {
  return Object.values(obj).every(v => ['', null].includes(v))
}

console.log(checkEmptyOrNull(obj1))
console.log(checkEmptyOrNull(obj2))
console.log(checkEmptyOrNull(obj3))
console.log(checkEmptyOrNull(obj4))
console.log(checkEmptyOrNull(obj5))
```